# Unable to open Azure app service URL in iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, microsoft-teams, content-security-policy

I have a MS Teams tab app service on azure. I am trying to open URL of my app service in iframe on my website. It gives me error as "Refused to frame 'https://testtabapp.azurewebsites.net/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.sharepoint.com outlook.office.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.office.com testtabapp.azurewebsites.net"."

I tried adding

```
express.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader(
    "Content-Security-Policy",
"default-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://testtabappp.in/; frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.sharepoint.com outlook.office.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.office.com testtabapp.azurewebsites.net testtabapp.in "
  );
  next();
});
```

this code in my server.ts file but it is not working

Comment: Could you please try to add the domain of your website to the frame-ancestors directive in your CSP and check if it helps? `express.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader( "Content-Security-Policy",
    "default-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://testtabappp.in/; frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.sharepoint.com outlook.office.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.office.com testtabapp.azurewebsites.net testtabapp.in YOUR_WEBSITE_DOMAIN"
  ); next();
});`

Comment: Replace `YOUR_WEBSITE_DOMAIN` with the domain of your website where you're trying to load the app in an iframe.
Please note that the domain should be specified without the `http://` or `https://` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new CSP doesn't alter the existing CSP. All content now needs to pass both the existing and the new CSP. You will still see the same errors as you're being blocked by the existing CSP. A possibility to configure the built in CSP is likely your only option.